# TypeScript + React: Make conditional component with conditional props type safe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to render a component based on a string, so I came up with this solution:

```js
const MY_COMPONENTS = {
  COMPONENT_ONE: "ComponentOne",
  COMPONENT_TWO: "ComponentTwo"
};

const MY_COMPONENTS_MAP = {
  [MY_COMPONENTS.COMPONENT_ONE]: ComponentOne,
  [MY_COMPONENTS.COMPONENT_TWO]: ComponentTwo
};
```

Both components have a different type structure, so TypeScript complains, even though the conditional rendering works as expected:

```js
// Change to 'ComponentOne' or 'ComponentTwo' to see a different component being rendered
const COMPONENT_TO_RENDER = "ComponentOne";

export default function App() {
  const ConditionalComponent = MY_COMPONENTS_MAP[COMPONENT_TO_RENDER];

  const getConditionalComponentProps = (component: string) => {
    switch (component) {
      case MY_COMPONENTS.COMPONENT_ONE:
        return {
          id: "123",
          name: "Jhon Doe"
        };
      case MY_COMPONENTS.COMPONENT_TWO:
        return {
          logLoremIpsum: () => console.log("Lorem Ipsum!")
        };
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* How to fix the type error below? */}
      <ConditionalComponent
        {...getConditionalComponentProps(COMPONENT_TO_RENDER)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here's a working demo where you can see more](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-lewin-2gu24c?file=/src/App.tsx), including the props that ComponentOne and ComponentTwo are taking.

Is there any way to make `ConditionalComponent` work with TypeScript? Or is there a different approach I can take for this conditional component rendering?

The full TypeScript error is:

```
Type '{} | { id: string; name: string; logLoremIpsum?: undefined; } | { logLoremIpsum: () => void; id?: undefined; name?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ComponentOneProps & ComponentTwoProps'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ComponentOneProps': id, namets(2322)`
```

Comment: I tried messing around with this to no real avail; setting the return type of `getConditionalComponentProps` to `any` dismisses the type error if your concern is just the message itself.

Comment: I'll add `any`, was just wondering if there was any different approach as to not sacrifice the type safety, thank you.